# rpk topic create: topic config canonical reference needed

Tags: message-queue, redpanda

According to https://vectorized.io/docs/rpk-commands#topic-create `rpk topic create` has an option which we can use to provide custom options for topics

```
  -c, --topic-config stringArray   Config entries in the format <key>:<value>. May be used multiple times to add more entries.
```

Unfortunately it does not have a link to the list of topic options we can choose from and I haven't find redpanda topic options reference, no matter how I tried.

I would like to have a link to the reference documentation to the complete list of available topic options. Alternatively some pointers about how can I find out this list and the meaning of its items.